# Iteration of Hash: JekyII

Tags: for-loop, iteration, jekyll, shopify, liquid

Hi I was trying to extract this (**"Polk County", "short_name" => "Polk County"**)
in the 3rd row of this Hash but I can seem to get just the "Polk County"
this is my current code:

```
{% for county_hash in location.address_components %}
 {% for county in county_hash %}
  {{ county.long_name }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{
"0" => {
    "long_name" => "426", "short_name" => "426", "types" => ["street_number"]
}, "1" => {
    "long_name" => "Swanee Drive", "short_name" => "Swanee Dr", "types" => ["route"]
}, "2" => {
    "long_name" => "Livingston", "short_name" => "Livingston", "types" => ["locality", "political"]
}, "3" => {
    "long_name" => "Polk County", "short_name" => "Polk County", "types" => ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
}, "4" => {
    "long_name" => "Texas", "short_name" => "TX", "types" => ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
}, "5" => {
    "long_name" => "United States", "short_name" => "US", "types" => ["country", "political"]
}, "6" => {
    "long_name" => "77351", "short_name" => "77351", "types" => ["postal_code"]
}, "7" => {
    "long_name" => "8238", "short_name" => "8238", "types" => ["postal_code_suffix"]
}
```

}

Comment: What does location file looks like?

Comment: It will display LocationDrop Method which is capable of displaying addess, state postal etc.

Comment: Using the iteration code above will get me this results

'426
Swanee Drive
Livingston
Polk County
Texas
United States
77351
8238'

but I only need "Polk County"

Comment: There is missing information to completely understand the question, you should post the relevant files content https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not clear on what exactly you are trying to ask here, the following code

```
{% for county_hash in location.address_components %}
  {% for county in county_hash %}
    {{ county.long_name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

will `return` a string of all `long_names` namely `426 Swanee Drive Livingston Polk County Texas United States 77351 8238` like you mentioned in the comments.

---

If you need to get just `Polk County`, you'll have to use the `where` filter:

```
{% for county_hash in location.address_components %}
  {% for county in county_hash %}
    {{ county.long_name | where: "shortname", "Polk County" }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi I think that will work but, the word "Polky" will always change depending on location. Exept for the word "County".  The reason I want to get this is to display the county where the listings in my website is located.

Comment: Is there an "if" statement that I can use to check if it has "county" and then assign it to a variable so I can use it to display county? {{county.thisCounty}}

Comment: `"The reason I want to get this is to display the county where the listings in my website is located."` --- Ben --- Could you please update the question with a couple of example scenarios? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, 
This method works for me.

```
{% for county_hash in location.address_components %}
  {% for county in county_hash %}
    {% if county.long_name contains 'County' %}
     {{ county.long_name }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[breadcrumbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XojGl.png)